# In golang gin simple template example, how do you render a string without quotes?

Tags: templates, go, go-gin

Using example golang gin code from README:

```
func main() {

  router := gin.Default()

  router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
  router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl",
      gin.H{
        "foo": "bar",
      })
  }
}

// in template index.tmpl

<script>
{{.foo}}
</script>

// result in html

<script>
"bar"
</script>
```

But how can I get it without the quotes, I need just `bar` vs `"bar"`?

Comment: "foo":   template.HTML("<script>bar</script>"), seems to work if you render the entire script tag and remove the script tags from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the template package implements an HTML context aware engine to provide injection safe html.

In other words it knows it executes inside a script tag, thus it does not output raw string but json encoded strings compatible with js.

To fix it, unlike the comment suggests, make the string a `template.JS` value and the security measures will not attempt to protect the strings.

ref
- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

> Package template (html/template) implements data-driven templates for
>   generating HTML output safe against code injection.

- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS

> Use of this type presents a security risk: the encapsulated content
>   should come from a trusted source, as it will be included verbatim in
>   the template output.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    c := `<script>
{{.foo}}
{{.oof}}
</script>`
    d := map[string]interface{}{"foo": "bar", "oof": template.JS("rab")}
    template.Must(template.New("").Parse(c)).Execute(os.Stdout, d)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6qLnc9ALCeC